# django json loop

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

How to i get the values of particular field for Example: son, flower(Title) from

`json = [{"pk": 1, "model": "book", "fields": {"title": "sum", "author": "son", "description": "dfg"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "book", "fields": {"title": "Eradication", "author": "flower", "description": "nandhu"}}]`

using ajax in ajax success part. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: google for javascript "for loops" this is not about django, is about js!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, you can just use the [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function as such:

```
$.getJSON('{% url your_json_view %}', function(data) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].fields.author == 'flower') {
            alert('I got the book by flower');
        }
    }
});
```

Just to make sure, here's the python view that goes with it:

```
def your_json_view(request):
    # ... build your data
    return http.HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

The url should be defined nicely with a name too:

```
url(r'/your/json/view/', 'your_json_view', name='your_json_view')
```

Comment: Then you should add console.log(data[i]) and stuff like that before the if condition. Check the output in firebug or webkit inspector.